# Disable '.show-more' button if 20 or more divs are present?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to say if there are less than 20 .news-item divs present on the page, enable the show more button. Otherwise, if there are more than 20 .news-items, hide the button. What is wrong with my code?

HTML:

```
<div class="news-item"></div>
<div class="news-item:hidden"></div>
 <button class="btn show-more">Show More</button>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var newsNum = $('.news-item').size();
console.log(newsNum);
$('.show-more').click(function () {
    $('.news-item:hidden').slice(0,3).addClass('show');
    $( ".news-item:hidden" ).slice( 0,5).removeClass("hidden");
    if(newsNum  >= 20) {
        $(this).attr("disabled", true).hide();
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).attr("disabled", false);
    }
});

});
```

Comment: hidden is a bootstrap class. I want that div to appear when the button is clicked.

Comment: Yes, `.hidden` is a bootstrap class, but not `:hidden`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what should happens when user will click the button, but checking for `<div class="news-item">` quantity is simple:

```
var newsItemsCount = $(".news-item").length;
var btnShowMore = $(".btn.show-more");

if (newsItemsCount >= 20) {
    btnShowMore.show();
} else {
    btnShowMore.hide();
}
```

You can use it in all necessary handlers.

And, yes, using of CSS class name `news-item:hidden` in markup is incorrect.

**Update**

Ok-ok! There is a disambiguation with word "incorrect". I wish to remake previous sentence to "Try to avoid of using CSS class names alike `news-item:hidden`". They are just making you jQuery code more complex without any functional benefits. Here is simple example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Lh71cqq/2/).

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I say "incorrect". You can use it. It will not cause problems with markup but with some jQuery selectors - oh yes. But why?!

Comment: The CSS selector grammar doesn't allow "news-item:hidden" as a class name. That's what @AndrewOrlov is getting at.

Comment: There's no such class in BS anyway.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Aha. There are many issues with initial question.

Answer (score 0):

**There's no such `:hidden` Bootstrap class: *[See for yourself](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css)***

**It should be `.hidden`**

- Get all the items and their count
- Get all the visible ones and also count them
- Set an increment *(revealer)* factor of 3 or whatever you want
- Reveal items 3 by 3 and when the number of visible news reaches the total number of news: toggle-hide the button

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  
  var $newsAll         = $('.news-item');
  var newsAllTotal     = $newsAll.length;          
  
  var $newsVisible     = $newsAll.not(".hidden");
  var newsVisibleTotal = $newsVisible.length;
  
  var incrementBy = 3; // Reveal 3-by-3
  


  $('.show-more').click(function () {
    
    newsVisibleTotal += incrementBy;
    $newsAll.slice(0, newsVisibleTotal).addClass('show');
    $(this).toggle( newsAllTotal-1 >= newsVisibleTotal );
    
  });

});
```

```css
[class^=news-item]{
  background:#eee;
  padding:10px;
  margin:3px;
}

[class$=hidden]{
  display:none;
}
.show{
  display:block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="news-item">1</div>
<div class="news-item">2</div>
<div class="news-item">3</div>
<div class="news-item hidden">4</div>
<div class="news-item hidden">5</div>
<div class="news-item hidden">6</div>
<div class="news-item hidden">7</div>
<div class="news-item hidden">8</div>
<div class="news-item hidden">9</div>
<div class="news-item hidden">10</div>
<div class="news-item hidden">11</div>
<div class="news-item hidden">12</div>
<div class="news-item hidden">13</div>
<div class="news-item hidden">14</div>
<div class="news-item hidden">15</div>
<div class="news-item hidden">16</div>

  
 <button class="btn show-more">Show More</button>
```